# Question about short exact sequence of differential complexes

Tags: de-rham-cohomology

$0—>A—>B—>C—>0$ is a short exact sequence of differential complexes. I wonder why for any element $c$ belonging to $C$, it is true that $dc=0$.

Comment: Does $d$ denote the differential $C\xrightarrow{d} 0$?

Comment: @Zest No. $d$ is differential operator define on differential complex C.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of differential complexes, the notation d
typically represents the differential operator, which maps an element of one complex to the next. The property dc=0
for all c
in C
is a consequence of the exactness of the sequence at C
.
A short exact sequence of complexes 0→A→B→C→0
is exact at C
if the image of the differential map from B
to C
is equal to the kernel of the differential map from C
to 0
. But the kernel of any map to the zero object 0
is the entire domain, so in this case, it’s all of C
. Therefore, the image of the differential map from B
to C
must also be all of C
.
However, the only element that maps to 0
under the differential operator is 0
itself (since we’re in a complex, where the composition of two consecutive differentials is zero: d2=0
). Therefore, for all c
in C
, we must have dc=0